# Azure default NSG not blocking internet traffic

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-nsg

I am working with [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#-connect-to-a-web-service-hosted-within-a-virtual-network) and have setup the network diagram described in the article itself and gone a little further by adding a NSG.

Given the below diagram and context I am struggling to understand why I can hit my API directly when the NSG is only configured with the default rules of ALLOW VNET INBOUND, ALLOW AZURE LOAD BALANCER INBOUND and DENY ALL INBOUND

[Azure APIM with Networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBgRX.png)

In advance I will own to being truly terrible at networking, despite hours of studying.

Answer (score 0):

NSGs are not inline for App Service traffic destined for the App Service's public IP address, even if the App Services is VNET-integrated. If you have deployed APIM in front of the App Service, you still need to only allow APIM to connect to the App Service--which can be accomplished with client certificates.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions
APIM certs setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates

Comment: Wow.  I really didn't get that from the article, which is most likely on me I accept but still.  Thank you those links.  I will work through them.